# What IDE has the strongest support for Symfony framework?

Tags: php, ide, symfony1

I'm looking for an IDE with use with the [Symfony Framework](http://www.symfony-project.org).

I have a bit of experience using the [NetBeans 6.5 IDE](http://www.netbeans.org) but it does not always seem to complete the class methods, plus it doesn't seem to have any PHP code snippets built in.

Here are the features I would ideally like to have, in order of importance, from an IDE:

- Code completion of all the Symfony and Propel class methods (I can never remember them)
- Code templates,(class skeletons, HTML structures, Symfony templates?)
- Straight-forward code debugging
- Source Control

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you could wait, Symfony support is coming to Netbeans soon: http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=145913. I'll go with Zend Studio 5.5's  debugging and inspection features for the time being.

Comment: I still like the features the best on netbeans.  I'm really looking forward to when they finish the Symfony integration.

Answer (score 4):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) with [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)

Answer (score 4):

[Komodo IDE](https://www.activestate.com/blog/activestate-komodo-ide-now-open-source/) (or, without debugging and Source Control, the free [Komodo Edit](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit)) + [a set of commands for Komodo to use symfony tasks](https://web.archive.org/web/20160116140524/https://code.google.com/p/ksf/). does all your 4 points, and also works for Perl, Python, Ruby and Tcl.

Comment: Very interesting...I'm going to check this out as soon as I get the time.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>I recommend NetBeans. You can follow this tutorial: [Use NetBeans to setup a PHP Symfony project](http://peterlong.info/use-netbeans-to-setup-a-php-symfony-project/)</strike>

> A lot of things change. the above link is broken now. And Oracle owns Netbeans now. So, I do NOT recommend netbeans to you any more! Try gvim!

Comment: A lot of things change. the above link is broken now. And Oracle owns Netbeans now. So, I do NOT recommend netbeans to you any more! Try gvim!

Answer (score 4):

I've been using Symfony since version 0.6, and have used Zend Studio (both the earlier versions, and the later Eclipse based versions), Eclipse, Komodo, NetBeans, VIM, e TextEditor and Sublime Text.

I've recently switched to **[PHP Storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)**, and I have to say... It completely annihilates all the other options. Definitely my choice!

Answer (score 3):

Symfony is supported by NetBeans 6.8.

Answer (score 2):

As for me, it's Eclipse + PDT. 
But NetBeans already has support of phpDoc 1.4 (while PDT hasn't), so you can document (and IDE will be able to autocomplete) "magic" properties and methods. Doctrine users will surely appreciate that :)

**UPD:** Some time passed and I've moved to NetBeans first (it appeared lighter, faster and less complicated). Then I've used PhpStorm EAP, liked it and even bought a license :)

So, here and now my IDEs of choice are:

- NetBeans — free
- PhpStorm — paid, most intelligent (static source analysis is real killer feature)

Comment: For more infos check this link : http://symfony.com/marketplace/development-tools/phpstorm

Comment: The link no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use **PHPEDIT**, it is the software with the best support for all symfony versions,

you can watch a screencast of how easy can be develop symfony projects with phpedit.
[Link](http://www.waterproof.fr/%7Eshordeaux/phpedit-3.2/screencast/en/)

Comment: This is a pretty nice IDE so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Textmate for Symfony development. After getting the grip of it, it can be perfectly fit as well.

Comment: Textmate is a very powerful text editor, but not an IDE

Answer (score 1):

I used Eclipse PDT in the past, and switched to Netbeans a month ago... After having tried both, I would recommend Netbeans: It has better refactoring tools and it performs better in general.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say that netbeans edits perfectly YAML files (eclipse can't) and that it has one of the best CSS and HTML editors I have ever used.

In this moment, Netbeans is clearly better than Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Symfoclipse, a Symfony plugin for Eclipse + PDT environment. [Here's the link ;-)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100413151241/http://marketplace.eclipse.org:80/content/symfoclipse-symfony-framework-support-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

It's NetBeans for PHP. It supports symfony.

Answer (score 0):

PHPEdit blows away the competition.  Of course you have to pay for it, but it has support for SVN, GUI for all symfony commands, yaml editing, etc.

You get a lot for your money and makes development so much easier and faster.

You will make back your money with one project just off of the time you saved.

Comment: C'mon, these are marketing sentences.
- "PHPEdit blows away the competition."
- How?

- "You get a lot for your money and makes development so much easier and faster."
- On which terms development is being accelerated?

etc...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer old school, textmate or bbedit (which I am becoming a real fan of)